# c++11 dedicated "proxy constructors" delegating to private univeral reference constructor?

Tags: c++11

Reading Scott Meyer's book "Effective Modern C++", Item 24 (and following), and Item 41, I wonder that this book opposes:

1. the individual constructors for lvalue and rvalue parameters

to

2. a template'd universal constructor solution

It says, that 1. has the disadvantage to duplicate code. 
Whereas 2. has the disadvantage to potentially being used for unwanted types.

I wonder why the book does not mention a **mixed** model - as in the example code shown below.

It uses type-safe dedicated constructors for lvalue and rvalue but delegates to a single (private) generic implementation for "universal reference".
This **avoids** unwanted template types of a public "universal reference" constructor.

So is there is anything wrong with the approach below? Something I missed?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    class MyClass
    {
    private:

        enum class Dummy { Nop = 0 } ;

        template <class T>
        MyClass(Dummy, T&& data)
        : _data(std::forward<T>(data))
        {
            std::cout << "MyClass universal reference template c'tor" << std::endl;
        }

    public:

        // proxy c'tors delegating to universal reference c'tor
        MyClass (std::string const & data)
        : MyClass(Dummy::Nop, data)
        {
            std::cout << "MyClass lvalue c'tor" << std::endl;
        }

        MyClass (std::string && data)
        : MyClass(Dummy::Nop, std::move(data))
        {
            std::cout << "MyClass rvalue c'tor" << std::endl;
        }

    private:
        std::string _data;
    };

    int main(int, char**)
    {

        {
            std::string str("demo");
            MyClass myClass(str);
        }

        {
            MyClass myClass("hello, world");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: please add the relevant quotes. Avoid large dumps from the book to avoid copyright issues.

Comment: I had assumed the actual question stands on its own; does context from the book modify it?

Comment: I personally don't understand what he thinks the problem might be. And I don't have a copy of the book handy so for me at least no, the question doesn't stand on its own

Comment: the code example is **not** from the book. I actually wonder, that such (or similar is **not** in the book). Therefore i ask if i missed something.The book actually tells about both options, but each with it's pros & cons. So does the code above take the best of both of them? Or does it have some other general deficit?

Comment: you need `std::move(data)` on the move ctor. Other than that I don't see any problems.

Comment: Another question: Is there a chance to do without enum class Dummy? Can i request the template c'tor? E.g.using ":MyClass<std::string const &>(data)" in the MIL does not work :-(

Comment: i fixed the missing "std::move(data)" - thanks!

Comment: reading your first paragraph it is suggested that something in Scott Meyer's book says this is wrong. So please clarify the question.

Comment: now the question makes sense. And it's a good question actually.

Answer (score 0):

And now let's put the book down and do it the right way:

Pros:

1. Optimal efficiency
2. Correct type limitations
3. DRY

Cons:

1. None

-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

class MyClass
{

public:

    template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<std::string, T>::value>* = nullptr>
    MyClass(T&& data)
    : _data(std::forward<T>(data))
    {
        std::cout << "MyClass universal reference template c'tor" << std::endl;
    }

private:

    std::string _data;

};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    auto a = MyClass("hello"s);
    auto b = MyClass("world");


    const auto s = "Hello, World"s;
    auto s2 = "Hello, World";

    auto c = MyClass(s);
    auto d = MyClass(s2);

// won't compile
//    auto e = MyClass(10);

}
```